# generating wsdl to java using jax-ws(Dropwizard) - creating duplicate classes

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, maven-2, dropwizard

The below is the xsd file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Request">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="Extensions" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Message" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="Subset" minOccurs="0">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:attribute name="Code" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Alternate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="Preferences" minOccurs="0">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="Pref" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                    <xs:attribute name="Code" type="StringLength1to8" use="required"/>
                                                    <xs:attribute name="Level" type="xs:string" default="Preferred"/>
                                                </xs:complexType>
                                            </xs:element>
                                            <xs:element name="Extensions" minOccurs="0">
                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                        <xs:element name="IncludePref" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                                        <xs:element name="ExcludePref" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                                    </xs:sequence>
                                                </xs:complexType>
                                            </xs:element>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Below is the jax-ws binding file:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <bindings node="wsdl:definitions">
        <enableWrapperStyle>true</enableWrapperStyle>
        <enableAsyncMapping>true</enableAsyncMapping>
    </bindings>
    <bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"  version="2.1">
        <globalBindings>
            <simple />
        </globalBindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Preferences']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Extensions']/xs:complexType">
            <class name="AlternativeExtentions" />
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

When I tried to generate wsdl to java using jax-ws, its generating duplicate class **Extensions**. Tried with various options by changing binding file. Still I was not getting it right.

Can some one help me to understand what is it going wrong here.

maven config to build the above application is below

```
 <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <bindingDirectory>binding-xmls</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingFiles>
                                <!-- binding file shared above -->
                                <bindingFile>proxy.jax</bindingFile>
                            </bindingFiles>
                            <wsdlUrls><wsdlUrl>http://mywebservices.com/wsdl/v1.01/TestService.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                            </wsdlUrls>
                            <sourceDestDir>myproject/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
```